# Custom sorting in PHP Array - Like mysql ORDER BY FIELD(order_fied, 4, 1, 5, 2, 3)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have one dynamic array, for example with following elements:

```
$myArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

And I want my final array to be:

```
$finalArray = array(4, 1, 5, [whaterever]);
```

What's the best way to do custom sorting which is neither ascending or descending or doesn't follow any rule like this?
Thanks for your suggestions.

[Edit]
I have edited my question.

Comment: can you explain some more?

Comment: When you have array with certain values and you want the values to be re-ordered like 4 at first 3 at last (as mentioned in above example). So may be a extra function where you mention the sorting posting for values and will return the sorted version of that array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function. On the second argument, you should write a function that will decide how your array elements should be placed.

Something like this:

```
<?php
$myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

$properOrder = [4, 1, 5, 2, 3];
usort($myArray, function($a, $b) use($properOrder) {
    $index1 = array_search($a, $properOrder);
    $index2 = array_search($b, $properOrder);

    if ($index1 > $index2) {
        return 1;
    } else if ($index1 < $index2) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});

print_r($myArray);
```

Comment: It's not working now. I want to have final array to have `array(4, 1, 5, [whaterever])`

Comment: @MagePsycho 1st Your question is now different than the original, so consider asking a new question. 2nd You should try to edit the custom function on the answer so that it returns -1 when your index is not 4, 1 or 5. We are here to help, and to point you to the right direction. Not to do your homework or your job.

Comment: here it is - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35365385/custom-sorting-for-first-few-elements-of-an-array