# Custom sorting for first few elements of an array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a dynamic array, for example:

```
$myArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...);
```

How to sort `$myArray` to have elements in the following order:

```
$finalArray = array(4, 1, 5, 2, 3, ...);
```

where first 3 elements `4, 1, 5` are hardcoded, and the rest of the array `2, 3, ...` remain intact.

Comment: You want shuffle $myArray ?

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant Yes custom sorting `$myArray` should output as that of `$finalArray`

Comment: If you want a random shuffle, why you dont use http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php ?

Comment: What kind of sorting is this??? Is this sorting follow any algorithm?

Comment: FYI, It's not random shuffling. I want an array elements with values 4, 1 & 5 to be  placed at first and rest there after. Makes sense?

Comment: It shed some light, but does not make much sense without further explanations for cases not covered in the example. Please check if my edit is correct, and change it otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since order of first elements is predefined, there is no sorting:

```
$finalArray = array_merge([4,1,5],array_diff($myArray,[4,1,5]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`usort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

It let's you use a custom sorting function where you can do anything you wish.